# Minitoc for \appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, appendix, minitoc

I want my appendices to look like that in the toc (Appendix as a `\chapter`, not a `\section` and "Appendix" before the title):

> Apendix A Example 1
> A.1 Subtitle 1
> A.2 Subsubtitle 1
>
> Apendix B Example 2
> B.1 Subtitle 2
> B.2 Subsubtitle 2

I also want to keep the numbering of figure in appendices: A.1, A.2, B.1, B.2 and so on. I want to have a minitoc for each appendix

Here's below my mwe I created:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,french]{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\dominitoc

\usepackage{appendix}


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\appendix

\chapter*{Example 1}
\addstarredchapter{Apendix A Example 1}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{A.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{A.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.\arabic{figure}}
\minitoc

Content of appendix A


\chapter*{Example 2}
\addstarredchapter{Apendix B Example 2}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{B.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{B.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{B.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{B.\arabic{figure}}
\minitoc


Content of appendix B


\end{document}
```

With this code the titles are well displayed in the toc and the figure numbering is right but the minitoc and the chapter title with "Appendix A" are not displayed.

How to display minitoc and "Appendix A" in chapter title?

Comment: Please complete your code so people can compile it to reproduce the problem. It will matter which document class you're loading, for example, and you can include the packages which are essential to demonstrating the problem.